# Performant mean calculation across array of array elements

Tags: go

Apologies if this is a "please do my homework for me" style of question. But I was looking for advise from the community around performance of array operations in go.

My problem space: I am using Go to perform astrophotographic image calibration. To perform astrophotographic calibration, there is a requirement to calculate the average pixel element value across many multiples data arrays.

For argument sake let's give each sub-exposure a data array type `[]float32`.

What I want to have, is a function that can perform a stacking and mean for any number of these data arrays, i.e., for a good master bias frame a good number of bias frame sub-exposures are needed, and this could be in the region of 10 to 100, depending on how statistically thorough the end user needs to be.

Therefore, I have proposed that I would need a function setup like this:

```golang
func MeanFloat32Arrays(a [][]float32) ([]float32, error) {
  // calculate the mean across the array of arrays here
}
```

That is, I am happy for the user to call the function as follows:

m, err := MeanFloat32Arrays([][]float32{i.Dark.data, j.Bias.data, k.Bias.data, ... , z.Bias.data })

The construction of the arg var I feel is just another detail we can gloss over for the moment.

My problem: How do I optimise the "mean stacking" process for this function? That is to say, how should I go about making `MeanFloat32Arrays` as performant as possible?

My initial code is as follows (which passes the test suite outlined below):

```golang
func MeanFloat32Arrays(a [][]float32) ([]float32, error) {
    if len(a) == 0 {
        return nil, errors.New("to divide arrays they must be of same length")
    }

    m := make([]float32, len(a[0]))

    for i := range m {
        for j := range a {
            // Ensure that each sub-array has the same length as the first one:
            if len(a[j]) != len(a[0]) {
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("issue at array input %v: to compute the mean of multiple arrays the length of each array must be the same", i)
            }

            if a[j][i] == 0 {
                continue
            }

            m[i] += a[j][i]
        }

        m[i] /= float32(len(a))
    }

    return m, nil
}
```

My current unit test suite is as follows:

```golang
func TestMeanABC(t *testing.T) {
    a := []float32{10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}

    b := []float32{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

    c := []float32{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

    m, err := MeanFloat32Arrays([][]float32{a, b, c})

    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("error should be nil, but got %v", err)
    }

    if len(m) != len(a) {
        t.Errorf("result should be of same length as a")
    }

    if m[0] != 4 {
        t.Errorf("result should be 1, but got %v", m[0])
    }

    if m[1] != 4.333333333333333 {
        t.Errorf("result should be 1, but got %v", m[1])
    }

    if m[2] != 4.666666666666667 {
        t.Errorf("result should be 1, but got %v", m[2])
    }

    if m[3] != 5 {
        t.Errorf("result should be 1, but got %v", m[3])
    }

    if m[4] != 5.333333333333333 {
        t.Errorf("result should be 6 but got %v", m[4])
    }

    if m[5] != 5.666666666666667 {
        t.Errorf("result should be 6 but got %v", m[5])
    }

    //... Assume here that the mean calculation is correct for all other elements
}

func TestMeanABCD(t *testing.T) {
    a := []float32{10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}

    b := []float32{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

    c := []float32{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

    d := []float32{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

    m, err := MeanFloat32Arrays([][]float32{a, b, c, d})

    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("error should be nil, but got %v", err)
    }

    if len(m) != len(a) {
        t.Errorf("result should be of same length as a")
    }

    if m[0] != 3.25 {
        t.Errorf("result should be 1, but got %v", m[0])
    }

    if m[1] != 3.75 {
        t.Errorf("result should be 1, but got %v", m[1])
    }

    if m[2] != 4.25 {
        t.Errorf("result should be 1, but got %v", m[2])
    }

    if m[3] != 4.75 {
        t.Errorf("result should be 1, but got %v", m[3])
    }

    if m[4] != 5.25 {
        t.Errorf("result should be 6 but got %v", m[4])
    }

    if m[5] != 5.75 {
        t.Errorf("result should be 6 but got %v", m[5])
    }

    //... Assume here that the mean calculation is correct for all other elements
}

func TestMeanABNotEqualLengthPanic(t *testing.T) {
    a := []float32{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}

    b := []float32{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}

    _, err := MeanFloat32Arrays([][]float32{a, b})

    if err == nil {
        t.Errorf("error should not be nil for two arrays of unequal length")
    }
}
```

So my question, what tricks could I apply to reduce the linear behaviour of the function as much as possible, could I use multiple threads? Would this be thread safe? I'd welcome any comments as I am still in the phase of writing go as a hobbyist ...

Comment: You must iterate over each value, so O(n) is the best you can get. How are you imaging "use multiple threads" and "thread safe" apply to this problem? Have you created any benchmarks to determine what if anything might be improved? There is more likely to be easy optimizations around this function regarding the handling of the data than in the function itself.

Comment: I don't think parallelism will get you far with simple arithmetic like this. Have you benchmarked and profiled the code to see if the performance is acceptable? The only thing that jumps out at me from the code is that you're checking the length of each array multiple times which is certainly unnecessary.

Comment: Make sure your iteration order doesn't trash your memory caches. Depending on the actual workload it might even make sense to interleave the arrays. But honestly: Nobody can answer this type of question except you _after_ careful benchmarking.

Comment: There are lots of libraries out there that have highly optimized, GPU-acceleraed image processing routines. I would use OpenCV for what you're doing: https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga191389f8a0e58180bb13a727782cd461
And there are Go bindings for it: https://github.com/hybridgroup/gocv
You could spend a lot of time optimizing your `for` loop here and never get anywhere close to the performance of a mature image processing library.

Comment: Also, while Go is an awesome language for production code it would not be my first stop for basic scientific computing. Python with Pandas or NumPy will likely get you comparable or better performance for this problem.